# LDAP configuration error in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, authentication, windows-server-2008

I am using following configuration of my server configured in VM with Domain “my.net.mil”.[image: server configuration]

I had created one Group named “GISADMINGROUP”  and a user “gisadmin” member of GISADMINGROUP and another user “gisuser” a simple user. 
[image: users]

Now I am trying to establish Geoserver authentication provider using LDAP as setting  shown below: I think there is a problem with server url – http://sach/dc=my,dc=net.mil
[image: geoserver]

With above setting I am getting following errors.
[image: error]

Can anyone help me with the issue?

Comment: Did you try `http://sach.my.net.mil/dc=my,dc=net,dc=mil` as the `Server URL` field value? You may also need to specify a port number depending on how you configured your server.

Comment: It seems you are trying to use active directory. Try using ldap:// instead of http:// . ldap:// will automatically go to port 389.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. I set the format as BradHards and instead of http i had use ldap. Now working fine.